# Scanner text file not working

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to scan a text file with characters (`p`, `t`, `a`, ...) so that each letter will then match a certain image. But first I have to read this letter and then make that connection with an image.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(textfile);
int lenght = 0;
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {              
    try {
        for (int j = 0; j != 0; j++) {                      
            ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().addImage(Land);
            ArrayImages.add(Land);                  
        }
        char tipo = sc.next().charAt(0);            
        System.out.println(tipo);               
        if (tipo == 'p') {
            ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().addImage(pine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? what output do you get?

Comment: What is that `for` loop supposed to be doing?

Comment: i can´t read the character in text file

Comment: OK, but what IS happening?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, are you sure that you declared your Scanner correctly?
It should be something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("FilePath"));
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
   String letters = sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println(letters);
}
```

This way you can read every letter from your file.